# Should people with tachycardia avoid caffeine?

Tags: caffeine, heart

Well, caffeine increases the resting heart rate. If the resting heart rate of a person with tachycardia is 110 bpm, it may increase to 125 bpm after consuming 200 mg caffeine. My questions: Is having a constantly high resting heart rate (because of caffeine) dangerous?

Comment: If it is just from the sinus node, I don't think it would be. However tachycardia from atrial arrhythmia is dangerous.

Comment: @Caters Describing atrial tachycardias as dangerous is overly broad and misleading. Atrial fibrillation and flutter create an increased risk of stroke, which can be prevented with anticoagulants, but other than that atrial tachycardias are not dangerous. Ventricular tachycardias, on the other hand, are. Perhaps you're mixing them up?

Comment: It would depend entirely on the cause of the tachycardia so the question is too broad as stated. For example, there is some evidence that caffeine actually has beneficial qualities for patients with atrial fibrillation, contrary to longstanding common wisdom and medical practice.

Comment: @CareyGregory Seems like that could make a good answer, no? I agree the question is a bit broad but we get so many poor questions here that I think we can be a little less picky. "It depends on the source of tachycardia, for example for X __________ while for Y ___________" is a fairly parsimonious answer.

Comment: Atrial (sinus) tachycardia is not danger-free.  Elevated rates (especially >140) decreases diastolic filling time, thus reduces cardiac output and can lead to hypotension, ischemia, etc depending on the situation.  Stimulants including caffeine can precipitate arrythmias, depending on dose and the individual's physiology/pathophysiology. Problems in answering this question include: we don't know the underlying cause of resting HR of 110, whether there is any conductivity abnormality, the individual's dose response to the stimulant, history of ischemia or sensitivity to hypotension...

Comment: An answer could take a format of "Maybe, it depends on the situation. For A, ___; for B, ___; for C, ___" but the problem is the OP might actually be asking "can I safely take caffeine pills [note he wrote mg not cup of coffee] if I have chronic tachycardia" and that's really a question with many factors best left to his/her doctor.  We could restructure the question to be a little more generic, but I'm not sure how much that will help.

Comment: Missed tagging @CareyGregory

Comment: and @BryanKrause

Comment: @DoctorWhom Okay, perhaps I was a bit overly sanguine because some patients can be at risk, but for the vast majority of patients stroke is the only real concern with atrial arrhythmias. This is why I don't want to write an answer even though this is squarely up my alley. Covering all the details involves more time than I have at the moment.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yes I agree this answer could easily become quite long!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **regular caffeine consumer** will likely develop a partial or complete **tolerance** to many caffeine effects and side effects, including increased heart rate. Tolerance develops within few days of regular caffeine consumption and disappears within few days of caffeine discontinuation.

[Tolerance to the Humoral and Hemodynamic Effects of Caffeine in Man (PubMed Central, 1981)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC370671/pdf/jcinvest00468-0195.pdf)

> Acute caffeine in subjects who do not normally ingest methylxanthines
>   leads to increases in blood pressure, heart rate, plasma epinephrine,
>   plasma norepinephrine, plasma renin activity, and urinary
>   catecholamines. Using a double-blind design, the effects of chronic
>   caffeine administration on these same variables were assessed. **Near
>   complete tolerance,** in terms of both humoral and hemodynamic
>   variables, **developed over the first 1-4 days of caffeine. No
>   longterm effects of caffeine on blood pressure, heart rate, plasma
>   renin activity, plasma catecholamines, or urinary catecholamines could
>   be demonstrated.**

A **single caffeine dose** may increase blood pressure but not necessary heart rate in individuals with supraventricular tachicardia.

[A prospective placebo controlled randomized study of caffeine in patients with supraventricular tachycardia undergoing electrophysiologic testing (Wiley Online Library, 2015)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/jce.12504)

> Caffeine, at moderate intake (5 mg/kg), was associated with
>   significant increases in systolic and diastolic blood pressures, but
>   had no evidence of a significant effect on cardiac conduction and
>   refractoriness. Furthermore, no effect of caffeine on SVT induction or
>   more rapid rates of induced tachycardias was found.
>
> **the resting heart rate was not significantly different between both
>   groups** [caffeine vs placebo].

[Caffeine and Cardiac Arrhythmias: A Review of the Evidence (The American Journal of Medicine, 2011)](http://cafeesaude.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Arritmias-D-J-Pelchovitz-et-al-Am-J-Med-Vol-124-2011.pdf)

> Overall, the data suggest that in most patients, even those with known
>   or suspected arrhythmia, **caffeine in moderate doses is well
>   tolerated and there is therefore no reason to restrict ingestion of
>   caffeine.** Care should be taken to avoid caffeine in situations in
>   which catecholamines are thought to drive the arrhythmia, as well as
>   in patients who note sensitivity to caffeine.

---

Now, I personally cannot claim if caffeine consumption is or is not dangerous for individuals with tachycardia, but most doctors, for example, from [American Heart Association](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/Conditions/Arrhythmia/AboutArrhythmia/Tachycardia-Fast-Heart-Rate_UCM_302018_Article.jsp#.WtSAgy5uZpg)) still advise them to cut it down.